# how to get values from field which is out of form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form

```
<form:form commandName="cnd" class="form">
<div class="form-group form-group-label">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
            <label class="floating-label">Title</label>
            <form:input path="title" cssClass="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-label">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
            <label class="floating-label">Company</label>
            <form:input path="company" cssClass="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-label">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
            <label class="floating-label" >Location</label>
            <form:input path="location" cssClass="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-block waves-button waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal">Toggle Modal</a>                           

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-blue waves-button waves-effect waves-light">Sign In</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
</form:form>
```

when I click on the link in form which is

```
 <a class="btn btn-block waves-button waves-effect" data-toggle="cat" href="#modal">Show cat</a>
```

I want to show the following

```
<div aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade" id="cat" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xs">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-heading">
                    <a class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Seclect Categories</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-inner">
                    <select>
                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <p class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-flat btn-alt" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button><button class="btn btn-flat btn-alt" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">OK</button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to get values selected from select and submit them when I submit the form using Javascript, I'm unable to place the `select` field in form for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a javascript function.  You can either have the cat div loaded from the beginning and hidden using javascript to show/hide it or you can call it via Ajax.

I included the div in your form and set the style to hidden with javascript either revealing it or hiding it on click.  You can remove the if and just set to to display block when clicked if you don't want to hide it again.  It's worth noting that this will not clear the values.  If you want to clear values when closing it then you should call it with AJax and clear the div when closing.

```
<form:form commandName="cnd" class="form">
<div class="form-group form-group-label">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
            <label class="floating-label">Title</label>
            <form:input path="title" cssClass="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-label">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
            <label class="floating-label">Company</label>
            <form:input path="company" cssClass="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-label">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
            <label class="floating-label" >Location</label>
            <form:input path="location" cssClass="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-block waves-button waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal" onClick="swap(); return false">Toggle</a>
<div aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade" id="cat" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xs">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-heading">
                <a class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Seclect Categories</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-inner">
                <select>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <p class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-flat btn-alt" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button><button class="btn btn-flat btn-alt" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">OK</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-blue waves-button waves-effect waves-light">Sign In</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    

<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1

function swap() {
    if (counter%2 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('cat').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (counter%2 != 0) {
        document.getElementById('cat').style.display = 'block';
    }
    counter += 1;
}
</script>

</form:form>
```